# How to calculate and plot this integral?

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, numerics

Any help to integrate this equation:

$$
    \begin{eqnarray}
    p(k,q)&=&-16 H^2 q^2\int_{q_a}^q \int_{q_a}^q \frac{1}{\sqrt{H^2-k_1{^2}}}\sinh(\sqrt{H^2-k_1{^2}}(q-b))\frac{1}{H b}  
    \Big[m^2 y(b)^2 \nonumber\\
    &-&\frac{1}{H b}   y^{\prime 2}(b)\Big]+\frac{1}{\sqrt{H^2-k_2{^2}}}\sinh(\sqrt{H^2-k_2{^2}}(q-f)) \frac{1}{H b}  
    \Big[m^2 y^2(f) \nonumber\\
    &-&\frac{1}{H f}   Y^{\prime 2} (f)  \Big] d b ~d f   
    \end{eqnarray}
$$

where:

$y(b) =  c_1 b^{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{1+\frac{m^2}{H^2}}}+ c_2 b^{\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{1+\frac{m^2}{H^2}}},$

$y(f) =  c_1 f^{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{1+\frac{m^2}{H^2}}}+ c_2 f^{\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{1+\frac{m^2}{H^2}}}.$

Here is my naive trial:

I let $c_1=c_2=1$. Also let $k_1=k_2=k$. Let $m=H=100$ GeV. Also take $q_a=-100$.

```
y[b_] := c1*b^(1/2 + Sqrt[1 + m^2/H^2]) + c2*b^(1/2 - Sqrt[1 + m^2/H^2]);     

    y[f_] := c1*f^(1/2 + Sqrt[1 + m^2/H^2]) + c2*f^(1/2 - Sqrt[1 + m^2/H^2]); 

eq[k_,b_,f_,q_] := 
  -16 H^2 q^2 ( (1/Sqrt[H^2 - k1^2])*Sinh[Sqrt[H^2 - k1^2]*(q - b)]*(1/(H*b))*
       (m^2*y[b]^2 - (1/(H*b))*D[y[b], b]^2) + (1/Sqrt[H^2 - k2^2])*
       Sinh[Sqrt[H^2 - k2^2]*(q - f)]*(1/(H*b))*(m^2*y[f]^2 -  (1/(H*f))*D[y[f], f]^2) )
```

Then the integration should be taken in the limit where $q\to 0$

```
i1[k_?NumericQ, f_?NumericQ, q_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[eq[k, b, f, q], {b, -100, q}]

i2[k_?NumericQ, q_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[i1[k, f, q], {f, -100, q}]

eqq[k_] = Limit[i2[k, q], q -> 0]

Plot[eqq[k], {k, 0, 1}]
```

But this code doesn't work!

In the equation's reference [2309.11694](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2309.11694.pdf)
$H=H^\star=10^{14}=m=-q_a$ GeV, and the plot of $p(k,q)$ as a function of $k/H$ is given by:

[image]

Comment: In your code functions `y1,y2` are not defined.

Comment: @AlexTrounev. You mean `D[y[b], b]` ? Ok, edit it. There are only `y[b]` and `y[f]`.

Comment: Upper-case Y in expression is not defined.  Maybe a typo.

Comment: Additional context from Physics.SE:  [Calculating the power spectrum of the gravitational waves](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/785230/calculating-the-power-spectrum-of-the-gravitational-waves)

Comment: I suspect that something is wrong with the limits of your integration as you've defined them.  Tracing things back, you're integrating `eq[k,b,f,q]` over some region of `b`, `f`, and `q` that remains finite at all times.  But `eq[k, b, f, 0] = 0`, so your integral will be identically zero in the $q \to 0$ limit.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert. Take another a limit, say $q \to1$, also if the integration limits changed. There is something missing in the code that I have mentioned, cause it doesn't give any result.

Comment: You're calling  `NIntegrate` on an integral with symbolic parameters. You need to specify your parameter values `c1 = c2 = 1;`
`m = H = 100;` , and set `k1` and `k2` to `k`. 

I am also not sure if `Limit` will work with  inexact input

Comment: @MichaelSeifert. Anyhow the integration limits are taken from the paper and as shown in the graph.